# How to select current model in a 3 model system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models. Users have multiple Portfolios and Portfolios have multiple Assets.

When a user signs in, that makes him a `current_user` by `find_by_id`. When they first register, it creates a portfolio for them. That becomes the current_portfolio.

Subsequent to this, they can create portfolios which redirects them to the list of all their portfolios. Clicking the link to each will make that portfolio the current_portfolio.

```
@current_portfolio = current_user.portfolios.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

The show view for portfolios has an assets form so that they can quickly add assets to the portfolio. This is where I get stuck. Because the assets form is on the portfolios `show` view, my Asset controller needs to reference current_portfolio, but this is in my Portfolio controller.

Portfolio Controller:

```
def show
    @current_portfolio = current_user.portfolios.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @asset = @current_portfolio.assets.build
end
```

When the form is submitted, it goes to my Assets controller `Create` function. `Create` can't simply have `@current_portfolio` because it's on a different controller. I also can't use `find_by_id(params[:id])` because `:id` is not providing anything.

How do I reference the second model when I have 3 models? (Sorry I'm a newb to rails...)

EDIT Update: I thought I found the solution but realized it didn't work.

I passed `<%= hidden_field_tag :portfolio_id, params[:id]%>` in my form and set my Create in the Asset controller to be

```
def create
    @asset = Asset.new(params[:asset])
    @asset.save
end
```

but it's not getting the portfolio_id which is a required field in my model.

Full form in my view

```
<%= form_for(@asset) do |f| %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :portfolio_id, params[:id]%>
        <%= f.text_field :asset_symbol %>
        <%= f.text_field :shares %>
        <%= f.text_field :cost %>
        <%= f.text_field :purchase_date, :type=>'date' %>
        <%= f.submit "+ Add to Portfolio" %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: why do you want to store `current_portfolio` and `current_user`? You could use a resource nesting like `user/1/portfolio/45` then the current one is referenced by it's id.

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate I actually wrote that I store current_user with the `find_by_id` but I actually store it with a cookie so that it logs the person out after a certain time of inactivity. I also use it so that the current_user can't access a portfolio just by typing it in the URL. I never learned about nesting resources but I'll certainly check it out now. I don't need to store current_portfolio, I simply need to be able to select the current_portfolio when submitting the form that adds an Asset to that portfolio.

Comment: what does your forms look like in your view when you try to create

Comment: My guess would be that the portfolio_id in the hidden field isn't coming back as part of the asset hash. Maybe it's as simple as assigning the @asset.portfolio_id = params[:portfolio_id] before the save.  Check you logs to see EXACTLY what is coming back in the POST.

Comment: @railsdog Ah I see, the hash was coming back `:portfolio_id => 20 :asset=>{:asset_symbol=> etc}` for some reason it was outside of the asset form. I'm new to rails so not sure of the purpose of that but if you submit that as an answer railsdog I will accept. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the portfolio_id in the hidden field isn't coming back as part of the asset hash. Maybe it's as simple as assigning the @asset.portfolio_id = params[:portfolio_id] before the save. Check you logs to see EXACTLY what is coming back in the POST